# Please accept answers to your question

Tags: discussion

Looking at the questions, I have noticed that almost noone has accepted answers.

This should really change.

Comment: Give it some time, this site is only a few hours old. :) I usually leave my questions open for a day or two to collect a variety of answers to pick from.

Comment: I very seldom accept any answer within a day, since I want to give everyone a chance to answer.

Comment: I guess that we come from different other SE sites.

Answer (score 12):

In general it is advised to wait at least a day before accepting any answer. This gives other users the time to reply as well and maybe improve the overall quality more.

In addition, looking at the age of this site, I would say we should wait even longer, especially when there are answers that are not perfectly answering the question. After all this is still a closed beta and as such limited to a few users. If it opens up, we will probably see many new users and as such sources for more answers. And I am sure that there might be someone out there who could answer a question better than we did in private now.

Answer (score 3):

I agree that it's best to wait awhile before accepting, but if I'm happy with an answer after a few hours, I will accept it.  If someone comes up with an even better one later on I 
will be notified and can switch.  There's no rule that the top voted answer must be the accepted one.

People shouldn't feel discouraged to answer or comment or vote or edit answers, just because an answer has already been accepted.  I've noticed that people do appear to think an question is 'dead' after a while and don't go back and read new comments.  We need to respond to new inputs and try to improve things just like you would on a wiki.